# how to add javascript for ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i add javascript or jquery for the content loading from ajax ? for-example there is no element with class "ajax-loaded" when we click on a button element is created with class name "ajax-loaded" so how can we add javascript or jquery on this element ? i am searching for this issue from so much time but unable to find the solution . I have tried some illogical things from my own side like tried adding javascript on click of that button but it didnt worked for me , any solution ?

Comment: looks like you want `.addEventListener` perhaps?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add javascript". Maybe you want something like `document.querySelector(".ajax-loaded").addEventListener("click", () => console.log("clicked"));`?

Comment: no , actually there is one div load using ajax ... when i click on some button then a div loads ... i want to use javascript on that div that is loaded using ajax ...

Comment: but the issue is javascript is not working for the div loaded using ajax .

Comment: ajax is usually used to fetch raw data with javascript.  Are you fetching HTML with ajax and inserting it into your document?  Is that what you mean by "div loaded using ajax"?

Comment: yes that is what actually happening ... i am using one plugin that is doing this ... i want to use my own javascript on that element that is loading using ajax

Comment: The `querySelector/addEventListener` code I mentioned should work after you've inserted the HTML.   You'll have to post some code (simplest example that demonstrates the problem) so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222433/discussion-between-flutterer-and-user2740650).